# How to set flex-direction for <td> elements

Tags: html, reactjs, css, flexbox

This is the excerpt from the render function of one of my components, which is a `table`:

```
   return (
        ...
        <td>
           <div style={{ width: '100%' }}>50</div>
           {' '}
           <span className='percentage-sign'>%</span>
        </td>
        ...
    )
```

This `<td>` is acting up. I expect a render to look this way: `50 %` appearing in horizontal direction. Instead, I get it in vertical direction (`50` above `%`), because of `width: 100%`.

If it was not a `<td>` element, I would have fixed the issue with `flex-direction` style property, but since `<td>` has `display: table-cell`, I was not able to do so.

I tried wrapping the children of `<td>` into a div and setting `display: flex` there, but it removed the space between the `50` and `%`.

**Question:** How can I make this table data element to:

- Have a space between `50` and `%`
- Have them appear in a horizontal direction
- Have the child of a `<td>` span across the entire cell, filling the entire width

Answer (score 1):

What solved the issue is instead of adding a separate `<div>` for a number (50 in this case), I added all the `<td>` elements into that div:

```
   return (
    ...
    <td>
       <div style={{ width: '100%' }}>
          50
          {' '}
          <span className='percentage-sign'>%</span>
       </div>
    </td>
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it the early closing of the div?

```
return (
    ...
    <td>
       <div style={{ width: '100%' }}>50</div>
       {' '}
       <span className='percentage-sign'>%</span>
    </td>
    ...
)
```

Comment: No. The div is used only for the number `50`.

Comment: But it closes the div before the style attribute?

Comment: I looked at your code excerpt, so did not see that typo. Now corrected

Comment: Ah ok it confused me, so that was not the problem I see :) Sry